# Error on localizedStringWithFormat

Tags: nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to localize my app, but the app crashes when it encounters my localized strings, that use `localizedStringWithFormat`. Here's an example:

```
cell.productRangeLabel.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("Questions %s", comment: "Subtitle showing the number of questions on each pack"), product.info!.range)
```

In the debugger (LLDB), `product.info!.range` prints the correct string, and if I print the NSLocalizedString only, it outputs the correct translation ("Preguntas %s), but in combination with localizedStringWithFormat it gives me an error:

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Before localizing, that string worked fine (`"Questions \(product.info!.range)"`).

I don't know if this matters, but importing the xliff file was a nightmare. Xcode kept crashing, and I'm sure there are missing strings, but it eventually did create the Localizable.strings file.

***Update***: I was using the iPhone 6s (9.3) simulator when it crashed. Now I tried with the iPhone 4s (9.3), and it doesn't crash, but all strings that are variables are garbled, like: "Preguntas ☨^^" instead of "Preguntas 1-50"

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. I had to change all %s and %d to %@.